# Windows Start Menu folder structure

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

Can someone explain how the Windows 10 Start Menu works? I have installed Autodesk Revit 2019, and the shortcuts are in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Autodesk\Revit 2019`. But in the start menu I get an Autodesk folder, but no Revit 2019 folder. It seems as if Windows 10 only displays the first folder past `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`, and no mater what the folder structure is below that, Microsoft wants all the shortcuts displayed together.

Is this the correct understanding, that we get one folder level past Programs and that's it, as far as expression in the actual Start Menu? Or is there some secret sauce Autodesk is applying to the Autodesk folder but not the subfolders, to cause it to be respected in the Start Menu?

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 should aggregate any shortcuts that reside in lower folders.  For example, on my system I have VMware tools installed. The `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\VMware` folder contains one shortcut (VMware vSphere Client) and one folder (VMware vSphere PowerCLI) that contains 8 additional shortcuts. In the start menu, all 9 shortcuts appear under the "VMware" header and the PowerCLI folder is not shown. If I create another folder inside of `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\VMware\PowerCLI`, and add a shortcut there, I then have 10 shortcuts under VMware and still no indication that there are subfolders in the Start Menu.

Answer (score 0):

[Classic Shell](http://www.classicshell.net/) is your friend; may I suggest you take a look at its [review](https://www.pcworld.com/article/3067296/windows/how-to-get-windows-7s-start-menu-in-windows-10.html)?